# batch : problems with variable

Tags: batch-file

I try to create a game but when I do a if statement in a if statement it dont work and return 0 instead of -100 but its really -100 in the value because first I remove it 100 and then I test if the value of the variables is less than 10 but when I do a @echo on to see how cmd see the line it show up that it test if 0 is less than 0 but when it print the info it said I have -100 coin here is the part of my code

```
set /a coin-=%prixamel1%
if %coin% lss 0 (
    cls
    echo you dont have enough money
    set /a coin+=%prixamel1%
    timeout 3 >nul
    call :printmap
    goto :loop
)
```

Comment: Is this piece of code itself within a pair of parentheses? If so, please post the entire statement. If not, there would seem to be nothing amiss about the code.

Comment: Btw. to avoid problems with percent expansion, you could just use the variable name without explicit expanding, when using `set /a`, like `set /a coin+=prixamel1`

Comment: Your code as posted runs fine. Please show (the part of) the code, that fails.